# How to render an external vue file from return data inside a loop?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, loops, v-for, slot

I was using Prime Vue's tab panel (https://primefaces.org/primevue/tabview) and I'm trying to render the vue file for each tab content only with a `v-for` loop. The `{{ tab.content }}` is an external vue file. Is that possible for me to render the html view of it?

This is my code so far:

```html
<TabView scrollable>
  <TabPanel v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.title">
    <template #header>
      <img
        :src="tab.src"
        :width="tab.width"
        :height="tab.height"
      />
      <span x-style="margin-left: 10px;">{{ tab.title }}</span>
    </template>
    <div>{{ tab.content }}</div>
  </TabPanel>
</TabView>
```

I imported the external vue file `(CreateEmployee.vue)` which is the one that should be rendered. The `tabs` array is in the script tag below:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, reactive, onMounted } from 'vue'
import * as yup from 'yup'

import FormWizard from '@/components/stepper/FormWizard.vue'
import FormStep from '@/components/stepper/FormStep.vue'
import TabView from 'primevue/tabview'
import TabPanel from 'primevue/tabpanel'
import { useConfirm } from 'primevue/useconfirm'
import KustomerCreateEmployee from '@/views/apps/kustomer/CreateEmployee.vue'
let tabs: string[] = reactive([
  { 
    src: '/src/assets/apps/logo-1password.svg', 
    width: '30',
    height: '30',
    title: '1Password',
    content: KustomerCreateEmployee
  },
]);
</script>
```

And lastly, this is the external vue file that should render on the loop:

```html
<template>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Sample" />
</template>
```

I did try with these code but was only getting this result:

```
{ "__hmrId": "0429c5db", "__file": "/Users/jumarj.multiplymii/Documents/Jumar's Files/Work Related/Projects/Web Development/sandbox/dev-boarding-pass/client/src/views/apps/kustomer/CreateEmployee.vue" }
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Because in your current code you're not changing the vue template with each pass through the loop you don't need to do anything quite so involved

```
<TabView scrollable>
  <TabPanel v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.title">
    <template #header>
      <img
        :src="tab.src"
        :width="tab.width"
        :height="tab.height"
      />
      <span x-style="margin-left: 10px;">{{ tab.title }}</span>
    </template>
    <KustomerCreateEmployee />    

<!-- you can use the other parameters in your tab object to initialize any parameters you need to pass down to the component -->
  </TabPanel>
</TabView>
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, but there will be multiple <TabPanel/> and each has its own tab.content (external vue file).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `:is` attribute, and to allow the component to use `block` property and pass the current `block` object itself. Then just add `:key` while looping in the component.

```html
<TabPanel v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.title">
  <template #header>
    <img
      :src="tab.src"
      :width="tab.width"
      :height="tab.height"
    />
    <span x-style="margin-left: 10px;">{{ tab.title }}</span>
  </template>
  <div><component :is="tab.content" :key="tab.title"></component></div>
</TabPanel>
```